# How to make an image background that fits the whole page of a website

Tags: html, css

!http://www.splicemarketing.co.uk/images/blog/full-background-image.jpg
Can this also be acheived by angular js
Here is the css
`

```
.bg { 


    background: url(holiday-car-rental.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }`
```

here is the html

```
    `<div id="bg">
           <h1>TEXT TO BE PLACED ON TOP OF THE IMAGE</h1> 
           </div>`
```

Comment: `background-size: cover`

Comment: That only works if the image is in the css as a background. This image is in the HTML. Use width:100%. Blurry, but 100% for sure

Comment: @Paulie_D i just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle this with `css`, you need to make your div or header full screen

html

```
<div id="bg"><h1>TEXT TO BE PLACED ON TOP OF THE IMAGE</h1> </div >
```

css

```
#bg{      
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url(http://www.splicemarketing.co.uk/images/blog/full-background-image.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

see this [**PEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qydamg)

Comment: look at my code please why wont mine work i have edited my question

Comment: like i said you to make your div fullscreen by give it full height and full width, read my answer and again and check the link

Answer (score 0):

angular can't handle it. It has to be from the css. May be u can write a directive which takes srcurl and makes a html image element with those styles of css to stretch it as background.